# Why are php functions named so strangely?

Tags: php

It sometimes feels like a drunk person wrote all the functions for php...Some are combined words with no underscore, other times functions are randomly underscored...Like using 'strtolower' and 'str_replace'...why does the former not have underscores (like str_to_lower) and the later does?  and for that matter why is 'replace' the full word but 'str' isn't 'string'?  If we are shortening words why not "str_rep"?  Or better yet, why shorten anything and instead just make everything clear, obvious and readable, like "string_replace" and maybe consistently apply this to all functions in php?  Is there some reason for why these functions are so strangely named?  Is it just sloppy laziness in the language or do these apparent inconsistencies have some meaning?

Comment: It's the way it is because it's the way it is. Historical baggage. Bad planning. Splintered community. Lack of standards. A combination of all of these things. It's a well known complaint about PHP. Leading to semi-famous quotes such as *"I don't understand why people keep complaining about a lack of conventions in PHP. There are so many conventions to choose from!"*

Comment: Align some functions to Perl, a natural evolution of PHP, to name a few.

Comment: This question has no real reason to be here, it's not constructive and should be closed

Comment: It's a legitimate question about the PHP language, this is a section in stack overflow about PHP.  What more "reason" does the question need to be here?  I'd honestly like to know.  It's ridiculous that this question was "frozen".  This question was about HISTORICAL FACTS pertaining to the language...wtf?

Comment: @AllanSocks questions here at SO should be concrete, perhaps you could try http://programmers.stackexchange.com ([read up on the difference of the two](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow))

Comment: This is not a forum for discussions about opinions. Yours is that php functions were named by people who are drunk. That's your opinion, leave it off SO. The comments here are legitimate reasoning for the naming of functions. Perhaps you can Google some of the talks that Rasmus has done on this topic before.

Comment: My "opinion" that the language is inconsistent is not in fact "an opinion", it's a "demonstrable fact".  My question as to how this came to be is "concrete".  Deceze is the one who answered my question, but in a non-concrete sort of vague way, so I guess I'll thumbs that user up...and you for the advice to "google", lol.  BTW, saying something was designed like the person was drunk should not be offensive, unless you are emotionally invested in the language, it was just a colorful analogy not meant to offend.

Comment: And that's the problem with this question, there is no more concrete answer. It's not consistent because it's not consistent. Because obviously nobody enforced consistency. It's not that anybody sat down at any point and decided to name these things in the inconsistent way they are for some concrete reason. On the contrary, nobody ever sat down to lay out some rules (in time for it to matter), so the result is what you see.

Comment: Even if it was "formed organically" there must have been "organic entities" responsible for forming it that can be pointed to and named in a concrete sense.  However, it is understandable that such historical detail may be out of the scope of stackoverflow to answer.  This is why I gave your answer a thumbs up, even though I found it to not address the question with a concrete answer.  My interest in this question has dissipated since I asked it though, and I'm going to move on now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the history of PHP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History

It was developed organically by different people, what resulted in this inconsistent naming.